# VS Code can't find /usr/bin/bash

Tags: bash, manjaro, visual-studio-code

I have Manjaro Nibia 20.2.1 (5.10.12-1-MANJARO) on an Acer V5-171. I downloaded VS Code from the AUR repository with Pamac. As far as I can tell it works fine except when I want to access the terminal. Then I get an error:

```
The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "usr/bin/bash" does not exist.
```

I have reviewed the [Common Questions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_common-questions), as well as the [Troubleshoot Terminal launch failure](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/troubleshoot-terminal-launch) page. As far as I can tell the settings are right in VS Code. The values `terminal.integrated.shell.linux` is set to `\usr\bin\bash` and `terminal.integrated.automationShell.linux` as well. I have tried to set both to `\bin\bash` but I get the same error.

When I run VS Code with `code --log trace` I get a process log, but there are no errors in it. I tried isolating what I though might be the relevant part of the log concerning the terminal but I can't see what the problem might be:

```
[2021-02-15 11:06:44.702] [renderer1] [trace] CommandService#executeCommand workbench.actions.view.toggleProblems
[2021-02-15 11:06:44.821] [renderer1] [trace] [File Watcher (node.js)] [CHANGED] /home/plergux/.config/Code - OSS/logs/20210215T110414/renderer1.log
[2021-02-15 11:06:44.864] [renderer1] [trace] [storage state.vscdb] updateItems(): insert(Map(3) {__$__targetStorageMarker => {"workbench.panel.markers":1,"workbench.panel.output":1,"terminal":1,"workbench.explorer.views.state":1,"workbench.scm.views.state":1,"workbench.view.search.state":1,"output.activechannel":0,"debug.selectedroot":1,"workbench.view.debug.state":1,"workbench.centerededitorlayout.active":0,"workbench.panel.placeholderPanels":1,"workbench.panel.repl":1,"vscode.debug-auto-launch":1,"terminal.integrated.environmentVariableCollections":1,"history.entries":1,"memento/workbench.editor.walkThroughPart":1,"memento/workbench.editors.textResourceEditor":1,"memento/workbench.editors.files.textFileEditor":1,"workbench.view.debug.numberOfVisibleViews":0,"workbench.panel.markers.numberOfVisibleViews":0,"memento/workbench.panel.markers":0,"terminal.numberOfVisibleViews":0,"codelens/cache2":1,"workbench.view.extensions.state":1,"workbench.view.extensions.numberOfVisibleViews":0,"memento/workbench.view.extensions":0,"workbench.view.explorer.numberOfVisibleViews":0,"memento/workbench.editor.settings2":1,"suggest/memories/recentlyUsed":1,"memento/workbench.editors.logViewer":1,"memento/workbench.parts.editor":1,"editors.mru":1,"workbench.panel.hidden":0,"workbench.panelpart.activepanelid":0}, workbench.panel.hidden => false, workbench.panelpart.activepanelid => workbench.panel.markers}), delete(Set(0) {})
[2021-02-15 11:06:44.867] [renderer1] [trace] [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): BEGIN TRANSACTION
[2021-02-15 11:06:44.868] [renderer1] [trace] [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): INSERT INTO ItemTable VALUES ('__$__targetStorageMarker','{"workbench.panel.markers":1,"workbench.panel.output":1,"terminal":1,"workbench.explorer.views.state":1,"workbench.scm.views.state":1,"workbench.view.search.state":1,"output.activechannel":0,"debug.selectedroot":1,"workbench.view.debug.state":1,"workbench.centerededitorlayout.active":0,"workbench.panel.placeholderPanels":1,"workbench.panel.repl":1,"vscode.debug-auto-launch":1,"terminal.integrated.environmentVariableCollections":1,"history.entries":1,"memento/workbench.editor.walkThroughPart":1,"memento/workbench.editors.textResourceEditor":1,"memento/workbench.editors.files.textFileEditor":1,"workbench.view.debug.numberOfVisibleViews":0,"workbench.panel.markers.numberOfVisibleViews":0,"memento/workbench.panel.markers":0,"terminal.numberOfVisibleViews":0,"codelens/cache2":1,"workbench.view.extensions.state":1,"workbench.view.extensions.numberOfVisibleViews":0,"memento/workbench.view.extensions":0,"workbench.view.explorer.numberOfVisibleViews":0,"memento/workbench.editor.settings2":1,"suggest/memories/recentlyUsed":1,"memento/workbench.editors.logViewer":1,"memento/workbench.parts.editor":1,"editors.mru":1,"workbench.panel.hidden":0,"workbench.panelpart.activepanelid":0}'),('workbench.panel.hidden','false'),('workbench.panelpart.activepanelid','workbench.panel.markers')
[2021-02-15 11:06:44.868] [renderer1] [trace] [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): END TRANSACTION
[2021-02-15 11:06:45.021] [renderer1] [trace] [File Watcher (node.js)] >> normalized [CHANGED] /home/plergux/.config/Code - OSS/logs/20210215T110414/renderer1.log
[2021-02-15 11:06:45.069] [renderer1] [trace] [File Watcher (node.js)] [CHANGED] /home/plergux/.config/Code - OSS/logs/20210215T110414/main.log
[2021-02-15 11:06:45.270] [renderer1] [trace] [File Watcher (node.js)] >> normalized [CHANGED] /home/plergux/.config/Code - OSS/logs/20210215T110414/main.log
[2021-02-15 11:06:45.272] [renderer1] [trace] [File Watcher (node.js)] [CHANGED] /home/plergux/.config/Code - OSS/logs/20210215T110414/renderer1.log
[2021-02-15 11:06:45.473] [renderer1] [trace] [File Watcher (node.js)] >> normalized [CHANGED] /home/plergux/.config/Code - OSS/logs/20210215T110414/renderer1.log
[2021-02-15 11:06:47.473] [renderer1] [trace] [File Watcher (node.js)] [CHANGED] /home/plergux/.config/Code - OSS/logs/20210215T110414/renderer1.log
[2021-02-15 11:06:47.585] [renderer1] [trace] terminalInstance#ctor (id: 2) {}
[2021-02-15 11:06:47.728] [renderer1] [trace] [storage state.vscdb] updateItems(): insert(Map(1) {__$__targetStorageMarker => {"workbench.panel.markers":1,"workbench.panel.output":1,"terminal":1,"workbench.explorer.views.state":1,"workbench.scm.views.state":1,"workbench.view.search.state":1,"output.activechannel":0,"debug.selectedroot":1,"workbench.view.debug.state":1,"workbench.centerededitorlayout.active":0,"workbench.panel.placeholderPanels":1,"workbench.panel.repl":1,"vscode.debug-auto-launch":1,"terminal.integrated.environmentVariableCollections":1,"history.entries":1,"memento/workbench.editor.walkThroughPart":1,"memento/workbench.editors.textResourceEditor":1,"memento/workbench.editors.files.textFileEditor":1,"workbench.view.debug.numberOfVisibleViews":0,"workbench.panel.markers.numberOfVisibleViews":0,"memento/workbench.panel.markers":0,"terminal.numberOfVisibleViews":0,"codelens/cache2":1,"workbench.view.extensions.state":1,"workbench.view.extensions.numberOfVisibleViews":0,"memento/workbench.view.extensions":0,"workbench.view.explorer.numberOfVisibleViews":0,"memento/workbench.editor.settings2":1,"suggest/memories/recentlyUsed":1,"memento/workbench.editors.logViewer":1,"memento/workbench.parts.editor":1,"editors.mru":1,"workbench.panel.hidden":0}}), delete(Set(1) {workbench.panelpart.activepanelid})
[2021-02-15 11:06:47.731] [renderer1] [trace] [File Watcher (node.js)] >> normalized [CHANGED] /home/plergux/.config/Code - OSS/logs/20210215T110414/renderer1.log
[2021-02-15 11:06:47.740] [renderer1] [debug] Terminal process exit (id: 2) with code undefined
[2021-02-15 11:06:47.741] [renderer1] [debug] Terminal process exit (id: 2) state 1
[2021-02-15 11:06:47.741] [renderer1] [trace] terminalInstance#dispose (id: 2)
[2021-02-15 11:06:47.866] [renderer1] [trace] [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): BEGIN TRANSACTION
[2021-02-15 11:06:47.880] [renderer1] [trace] [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): INSERT INTO ItemTable VALUES ('__$__targetStorageMarker','{"workbench.panel.markers":1,"workbench.panel.output":1,"terminal":1,"workbench.explorer.views.state":1,"workbench.scm.views.state":1,"workbench.view.search.state":1,"output.activechannel":0,"debug.selectedroot":1,"workbench.view.debug.state":1,"workbench.centerededitorlayout.active":0,"workbench.panel.placeholderPanels":1,"workbench.panel.repl":1,"vscode.debug-auto-launch":1,"terminal.integrated.environmentVariableCollections":1,"history.entries":1,"memento/workbench.editor.walkThroughPart":1,"memento/workbench.editors.textResourceEditor":1,"memento/workbench.editors.files.textFileEditor":1,"workbench.view.debug.numberOfVisibleViews":0,"workbench.panel.markers.numberOfVisibleViews":0,"memento/workbench.panel.markers":0,"terminal.numberOfVisibleViews":0,"codelens/cache2":1,"workbench.view.extensions.state":1,"workbench.view.extensions.numberOfVisibleViews":0,"memento/workbench.view.extensions":0,"workbench.view.explorer.numberOfVisibleViews":0,"memento/workbench.editor.settings2":1,"suggest/memories/recentlyUsed":1,"memento/workbench.editors.logViewer":1,"memento/workbench.parts.editor":1,"editors.mru":1,"workbench.panel.hidden":0}')
[2021-02-15 11:06:47.885] [renderer1] [trace] [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): DELETE FROM ItemTable WHERE key IN ('workbench.panelpart.activepanelid')
[2021-02-15 11:06:47.886] [renderer1] [trace] [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): END TRANSACTION
[2021-02-15 11:06:48.045] [renderer1] [trace] [storage state.vscdb] updateItems(): insert(Map(1) {__$__targetStorageMarker => {"workbench.panel.markers":1,"workbench.panel.output":1,"terminal":1,"workbench.explorer.views.state":1,"workbench.scm.views.state":1,"workbench.view.search.state":1,"output.activechannel":0,"debug.selectedroot":1,"workbench.view.debug.state":1,"workbench.centerededitorlayout.active":0,"workbench.panel.placeholderPanels":1,"workbench.panel.repl":1,"vscode.debug-auto-launch":1,"terminal.integrated.environmentVariableCollections":1,"history.entries":1,"memento/workbench.editor.walkThroughPart":1,"memento/workbench.editors.textResourceEditor":1,"memento/workbench.editors.files.textFileEditor":1,"workbench.view.debug.numberOfVisibleViews":0,"workbench.panel.markers.numberOfVisibleViews":0,"memento/workbench.panel.markers":0,"terminal.numberOfVisibleViews":0,"codelens/cache2":1,"workbench.view.extensions.state":1,"workbench.view.extensions.numberOfVisibleViews":0,"memento/workbench.view.extensions":0,"workbench.view.explorer.numberOfVisibleViews":0,"memento/workbench.editor.settings2":1,"suggest/memories/recentlyUsed":1,"memento/workbench.editors.logViewer":1,"memento/workbench.parts.editor":1,"editors.mru":1}}), delete(Set(1) {workbench.panel.hidden})
[2021-02-15 11:06:48.048] [renderer1] [trace] [File Watcher (node.js)] [CHANGED] /home/plergux/.config/Code - OSS/logs/20210215T110414/renderer1.log
[2021-02-15 11:06:48.049] [renderer1] [trace] [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): BEGIN TRANSACTION
[2021-02-15 11:06:48.049] [renderer1] [trace] [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): INSERT INTO ItemTable VALUES ('__$__targetStorageMarker','{"workbench.panel.markers":1,"workbench.panel.output":1,"terminal":1,"workbench.explorer.views.state":1,"workbench.scm.views.state":1,"workbench.view.search.state":1,"output.activechannel":0,"debug.selectedroot":1,"workbench.view.debug.state":1,"workbench.centerededitorlayout.active":0,"workbench.panel.placeholderPanels":1,"workbench.panel.repl":1,"vscode.debug-auto-launch":1,"terminal.integrated.environmentVariableCollections":1,"history.entries":1,"memento/workbench.editor.walkThroughPart":1,"memento/workbench.editors.textResourceEditor":1,"memento/workbench.editors.files.textFileEditor":1,"workbench.view.debug.numberOfVisibleViews":0,"workbench.panel.markers.numberOfVisibleViews":0,"memento/workbench.panel.markers":0,"terminal.numberOfVisibleViews":0,"codelens/cache2":1,"workbench.view.extensions.state":1,"workbench.view.extensions.numberOfVisibleViews":0,"memento/workbench.view.extensions":0,"workbench.view.explorer.numberOfVisibleViews":0,"memento/workbench.editor.settings2":1,"suggest/memories/recentlyUsed":1,"memento/workbench.editors.logViewer":1,"memento/workbench.parts.editor":1,"editors.mru":1}')
[2021-02-15 11:06:48.050] [renderer1] [trace] [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): DELETE FROM ItemTable WHERE key IN ('workbench.panel.hidden')
[2021-02-15 11:06:48.051] [renderer1] [trace] [storage state.vscdb] Trace (event): END TRANSACTION
```

Please advise.

Comment: Are the settings really referring to the pathnames by backslash?   If so, please replace them with forward slashes and try again.  Something is not quite right, as the error refers to `usr/bin/bash` which is again completely different from `/usr/bin/bash`

Comment: @chexum ok, just shoot me now. it was indeed not '/usr/bin/bash' in the settings like I said, it was 'usr/bin/bash'. it works fine now. Talk about embarrassing. :<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lesson learned: Check! and check again! And when you think you've checked enough, check everything over once more!

Due to some strange blindness I was completely unable to see that what was set in `terminal.integrated.shell.linux` was not `\usr\bin\bash` like it should have been but `usr\bin\bash`, missing the initial slash `\`. I do not know how I did that but I suppose looking like a fool for a little bit is worth it for learning. That's my story and I'm sticking to it.